# What is wrong with this read function?

Tags: c++

Sorry for posting a wall of text with code, but I cant seem to figure out why the struct vector isn't getting the values.

```
void load() {
    list.clear(); 
    vector<string> tag;
    vector<int> points;
    ifstream scorelist, namelist;
    scorelist.open("score.txt");
    if (scorelist.is_open()) {
        int scores;
        while (scorelist.good()) {
            cin >> scores;
            points.push_back(scores);
        }
        scorelist.close();
    }

    namelist.open("name.txt");
    if (namelist.is_open()) {
        string text;
        while (namelist.good()) {
            getline(namelist, text);
            tag.push_back(text);
        }
        namelist.close();
    }

    players games; //Players a struct with elements string name, int score
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        games.score = points[i];
        games.name = tag[i];
        list.push_back(games); //list is a vector<players>
    }
}
```

If I for example would write `cout << list[0].name` here nothing happens, the txt's has values.

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code in a debugger? Do the files open correctly?

Comment: You never check if the files could really be opened. You should add an `else` branch and print an error message there.

Comment: _"wall of text"_ That's certainly not what's considered a _wall of text_ here. The length of text and code is fine.

Comment: Thanks everyone, really weird, the scorelist >> scores; didn't fix it alone somehow, but I also had to add two else statements. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the scores from `cin` instead of from the `scorelist` stream. Change:

```
cin >> scores;
```

To:

```
scorelist >> scores;
```

Comment: Good point but it would cause an infinite loop unless there are other problems